# asp.NET LINQ Delete from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have a SQL Server database with 2 tables:

t1 - Category

```
Id
Name
```

t2- Product

```
Id
Name
CategoryId
```

I want to delete a row from the `Category` table, but since I have the foreign key I need to handle the products that has the `CategoryId` I want to delete.

So I did this:

```
var ProdCatID = (from prod in DataContext.Products
                 where prod.CategoryId == Convert.ToInt32(Id)
                 select prod).First();

ProdCatID.CategoryId = null;
DataContext.SubmitChanges();

var DelCat = (from cat in DataContext.Categories
             where cat.Id == Convert.ToInt32(Id)
             select cat).ToList();

DataContext.Categories.DeleteAllOnSubmit(DelCat);
DataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

What I`m trying to do is to check if there is any product with that`CategoryId`, if there is - I want to set the`CategoryID`to null and then delete the row from the`Category` table.

It is working when I have a product with a `CategoryId` but when I can't delete it.

Any ideas?

Comment: where cat.Id == Convert.ToInt32(Id) will never handle the case where a product has a null category ID.

Comment: It is working when a CategoryId is used by a product. But when the CategroId is not used by any product I can`t delete it. why?

Comment: do you have child records perhaps.. you have to make sure that if there are 1 to many relationships etc.. that you delete from bottom up meaning the parent record will be the last to be deleted.. this will prevent having orphan records in your Database.. also why don't you wrap the code around a try catch where you are trying to delete and tell us what the error message is.. that will help you to understand why things are not being deleted..

Comment: This is what I got in try - catch : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1):

You're only setting the first product that has this CategoryID to null - you need to handle all products that have that ID !

```
var products = (from prod in DataContext.Products
                where prod.CategoryId == Convert.ToInt32(Id)
                select prod).ToList();

foreach(Product p in products)
{
    p.CategoryId = null;
}

DataContext.SubmitChanges();

.....
```

After that, now you should be able to delete the category from the table

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH !!! I can`t vote for your answer but you helped me! I got my mistake ... again - thank you very much!

Comment: @Peter: but you can [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998) !! :-) ;-) :-) This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 0):

Simple!
Change the Product table configuration in Database!

```
ALTER TABLE Product 
ADD CONSTRAINT 'Category_FK'
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId)
    REFERENCES Category(Id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL;
```

whenever you delete a primary key will automatically put null!

Answer (score 0):

Cascade on Delete is there in entity framework. Cascade delete automatically deletes dependent records or set null to foreignkey properties when the principal record is deleted.

This is one to many reletionship between parent and child

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasOptional(a => a.UserDetail)
        .WithOptionalDependent()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

For more details check this: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/cascade-delete-in-code-first.aspx